# Choosing rows from a dataframe based on multiple functions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df with a column "A". How do I choose a subset of df based on multiple conditions. I am trying:

```
train.loc[(train["A"] != 2) or (train["A"] != 10)]
```

The or operator doesnt seem to be working. How can I fix this? I got the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-e949fa2bb478> in <module>
----> 1 sub_train.loc[(sub_train["primary_use"] != 2) or (sub_train["primary_use"] != 10), "year_built"]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1553             "The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1554             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().".format(
-> 1555                 self.__class__.__name__
   1556             )
   1557         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `|` for bitwise `OR` or `&` for bitwise `AND`, also `loc` is not necessary:

```
#filter 2 or 10
train[(train["A"] == 2) | (train["A"] == 10)]
#filter not 2 and not 10
train[(train["A"] != 2) & (train["A"] != 10)]
```

If want also select some columns then is necessary:

```
train.loc[(train["A"] == 2) | (train["A"] == 10), 'B']
```

---

Comment: This mask would not filter anything. I think he wants `&`..

Answer (score 2):

you need `|` instead of `OR` to do logic with Series:

```
train.loc[(train["A"] != 2) | (train["A"] != 10)]
```

To not worry about parentheses use [`Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html).
`loc` here in principle is not necessary if you do not want to select a specific column:

```
train[train["A"].ne(2) | train["A"].ne(10)]
```

---

But I think your logic is wrong since this mask does not filter 
If the value is 2 it will not be filtered because it is different from 10 and vice versa. I think you want[`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) + `~`:

```
train[~train["A"].isin([2,10])]
```

or `&`

```
train[train["A"].ne(2) & train["A"].ne(10)]
```